# How to find all Eulerian paths of De Bruijin graph

Tags: perl, graph, path, depth-first-search

I need to to Deep First Search in Perl to find all possible Eulerian paths of my graph and then select the longest one. However, I do not know how to implement this in Perl. This is an issue of finding the best alignment from the DE Bruijin Graph.
Could anyone help me?

I can just find one path, so each time I run my script, one random path is printed. For this, each time I traversed an edge, I put value 1 in the has for this edge.

My hash is like this:

```
'ATTCA' => {
                    'TTCAA' => [
                                 4,
                                 0
                               ],
                    'TTCAT' => [
                                 1,
                                 0
                               ]
                  },
       'TTCGT' => {
                    'TCGTT' => [
                                 1,
                                 0
                               ],
                    'TCGTA' => [
                                 1,
                                 0
                               ]
                  },
       'AGAAG' => {
                    'GAAGT' => [
                                 1,
                                 0
                               ]
                  },
```

The first value of the hash is the frequency of appearance of the edge, whereas the second one is the flag I use to know if it has been traversed.

I use a recursive function for the nodes I know have to start the path.

```
sub get_alignment() {
    my ($hs, $kmer, $nodesary, $lvl) = @_;
    # hs is the hash that I have shown, $kmer is the starting node, $nodesary is the new array with the succesion of keys that will be the path and $lvl is the number of the key.
    push @{ $nodesary }, $kmer;
    # adding a node to the array of words storing current sentence
    exists($hs->{$kmer}) || return;
    # exit recursion if current key corresponds to a terminal node
    my @childs = keys %{ $hs->{$kmer} };
    my $child;
    #We need a loop in order to traverse all the possible edges
    for(my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@childs) ; $i++) {
        $child = $childs[$i];
        if ( $hs->{$kmer}{$child}[1] == 0) {
            $hs->{$kmer}{$child}[1] = 1;
            last;
             #If we have already taken this value, we exit the loop 
        };
    };
    if (scalar( @{ $nodesary} )< scalar(keys %{ $hs })){    
        &get_alignment( $hs, $child, $nodesary, ++$lvl );
    }else{
        return;
    };
    # We call the function again, but with other parameters
};
```

So, with this, I put 1 in every traversed node and thanks to it, I know that I don't have to use it again. But, this only gives me one path.

Comment: Perhaps you should show us some code that would show us what you have tried and how it went wrong.

Comment: @Laubiotec: Please don't add details in a comment. Instead, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74590768/edit) to add the details there.

Comment: To clarify your question, please show a complete minimal runnable example, see [mcve] for more information